# C - How can open window explorer

Tags: c, console, console-application

I'm looking for function that **Open window explorer in C language**. I have found this [answer]**([How can I open Windows Explorer to a certain directory from within a WPF app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746079/how-can-i-open-windows-explorer-to-a-certain-directory-from-within-a-wpf-app))**, but this is C# language. **C can't have these features**? I use VS 2010.

I'm a beginner of C. So my question may seem ridiculously easy. But if you give me the answer I really appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: unicode: `ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"c:\\", 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`  or `ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "c:\\", 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

Comment: [Link to the above](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to open a certain directory in an explorer (here c:\program files) may be:

```
system("start \"\" \"c:\\program files\"");
```

Comment: It is really simplest solution for C language.

Comment: Simple one but platform dependent

Comment: `In function 'main':13:12: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\p' [enabled by default]system("start \"\" \"c:\program files\"");`. Fix by escaping `\\`

Answer (score 2):

Try using SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems() function, which can open files in windows explorer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762232(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Given the stslib.h library contains the system() function that let's you run shell commands, you should be able to run the command to open a new windows explorer window using the same command you would use in the terminal window.

A guideline: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-shutdown-computer