# C - How can get file by window explorer (console)

Tags: c, console

I'm looking for function that **open window explorer** and **get file the user selected**. I knew how to open window explorer to this my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226198/c-how-can-open-window-explorer), but I was asking the wrong question. I **want to enable read to the user selects a file.**

While trying to search, I found `OpenFileDialog()`. But this function looks like need GUI. Am I right? (My program runs only console)

**How can I open windows explorer on the console and get the file from the user?**

I'm a beginner of C. So my question may seem ridiculously easy. But if you give me the answer I really appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'get file user selected'? Do you want to open windows explorer and then open the file?

Comment: @moffeltje Yes, I do. You're right :) I'm Korean, so I don't know the explanation in English well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [`GetOpenFileName` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). (`OpenFileDialog` is for .NET applications; if you are using C then you are not using .NET).

According to MSDN, this has been superseded by the [Common Item Dialog system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but that system is much more complicated, requires COM and isn't necessary if you are only selecting files. `GetOpenFileName` will still work for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

To open Windows explorer:

```
system("start \"\" \"c:\\program files\"");
```

To open a specific file:

```
system("start \"\" \"c:\\program files\\file.txt\"");
```