# ShellExecute vs. Process.Start

Tags: c#, wpf, process

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1746093/309163) the author @Abel suggests using `ShellExecute` whenever `Process.Start` will not function.

When would I use `ShellExecute` - I did never have the situation that `Process.Start` did not work?

Furthermore, are there any advantages for using `ShellExecute` over `Process.Start`?

Comment: ShellExecute is a Windows API function. Won't have that in other environments.

Comment: Because he doesn't understand it and therefore blindly assumes it has magical powers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> are there any advantages for using ShellExecute over Process.Start

First, you need to understand what `ShellExecute` does. From [`ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When you use the operating system shell to start processes, you can
>   start any document (which is any registered file type associated with
>   an executable that has a default open action) and perform operations
>   on the file, such as printing, by using the Process object. When
>   UseShellExecute is false, you can start only executables by using the
>   Process object.

This means that it will allow you to open any file that has an assosicated file type, such as a given word document. Otherwise, you can only invoke executables. If you set this flag to true in `ProcessStartInfo`, internally, `Process.Start` [will invoke the same WinAPI call](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,e9edeff01b1851af,references):

```
public bool Start()
{
    Close();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = StartInfo;
    if (startInfo.FileName.Length == 0) 
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.FileNameMissing));

    if (startInfo.UseShellExecute) 
    {            
        return StartWithShellExecuteEx(startInfo);
    } 
    else
    {
        return StartWithCreateProcess(startInfo);
    }
}
```

When you invoke `ShellExecute`, you're using PInvoke to directly call WinAPI. With Process.Start, you're simply invoking the managed wrapper, which is usually more convenient to use.