# C# automatically open file location after downloading from ftp server

Tags: c#, download, ftp, file-location

I had a C# homework which I have to make a download manager, I already completed it.

This is my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;

    namespace DownloadDataFTP
   {
    public partial class ftpForm : Form
{
    public ftpForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private byte[] downloadedData;

    //Connects to the FTP server and downloads the file
    private void downloadFile(string FTPAddress, string filename, string username, string password)
    {
        downloadedData = new byte[0];

        try
        {
            //Create FTP request
            //Note: format is ftp://server.com/file.ext
            FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + "/" + filename) as FtpWebRequest;


            //Get the file size first (for progress bar)
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.KeepAlive = true; //don't close the connection

            int dataLength = (int)request.GetResponse().ContentLength;


            //Now get the actual data
            request = FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + "/" + filename) as FtpWebRequest;

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.KeepAlive = false; //close the connection when done

            //Set up progress bar
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = dataLength;
            lbProgress.Text = "0/" + dataLength.ToString();

            //Streams
            FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
            Stream reader = response.GetResponseStream();

            //Download to memory
            //Note: adjust the streams here to download directly to the hard drive
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //downloads in chuncks

            while (true)
            {
                Application.DoEvents(); //prevent application from crashing

                //Try to read the data
                int bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    //Nothing was read, finished downloading
                    progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Maximum;
                    lbProgress.Text = dataLength.ToString() + "/" + dataLength.ToString();

                    Application.DoEvents();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Write the downloaded data
                    memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    //Update the progress bar
                    if (progressBar1.Value + bytesRead <= progressBar1.Maximum)
                    {
                        progressBar1.Value += bytesRead;
                        lbProgress.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "/" + dataLength.ToString();

                        progressBar1.Refresh();
                        Application.DoEvents();
                    }
                }
            }

            //Convert the downloaded stream to a byte array
            downloadedData = memStream.ToArray();

            //Clean up
            reader.Close();
            memStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Downloaded Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection error. Please try again!");
        }

        txtData.Text = downloadedData.Length.ToString();
        this.Text = "Group 10 Download and Upload Manager";

        username = string.Empty;
        password = string.Empty;
    }

    //Upload file via FTP
    private void Upload(string FTPAddress, string filePath, string username, string password)
    {
        //Create FTP request
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + "/" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        //Load the file
        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];

        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        stream.Close();

        //Upload file
        Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        reqStream.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Uploaded Successfully");
    }

    //get file size for downloading
    private void FileSize_down(string FTPAddress, string filename, string username, string password)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + "/" + filename) as FtpWebRequest;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        long dataLength = (long)request.GetResponse().ContentLength;
        sizeFile.Text = dataLength.ToString();
    }



    //Connects to the FTP server and request the list of available files
    private void getFileList(string FTPAddress, string username, string password)
    {
        List<string> files = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            //Create FTP request
            FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress) as FtpWebRequest;

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.KeepAlive = false;


            FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                files.Add(reader.ReadLine());
            }

            //Clean-up
            reader.Close();
            responseStream.Close(); //redundant
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error connecting to the FTP Server");
        }

        username = string.Empty;
        password = string.Empty;

        this.Text = "Group 10 Download and Upload Manager"; //Back to normal title

        //If the list was successfully received, display it to the user
        //through a dialog
        if (files.Count != 0)
        {
            listDialogForm dialog = new listDialogForm(files);
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Update the File Name field
                txtFileName.Text = dialog.ChosenFile;
            }
        }
    }

    //Make sure the FTP server address has ftp:// at the beginning
    private void txtFTPAddress_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!txtFTPAddress.Text.StartsWith("ftp://"))
            txtFTPAddress.Text = "ftp://" + txtFTPAddress.Text;
    }

    private void btnGetList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtFTPAddress.Text != "ftp://" && txtFTPAddress.Text != string.Empty)
            getFileList(txtFTPAddress.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a FTP address");
    }

    //Download button
    private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtFTPAddress.Text != "ftp://" && txtFTPAddress.Text != string.Empty)
            if (txtFileName.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                downloadFile(txtFTPAddress.Text, txtFileName.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);

                saveFile1.FileName = txtFileName.Text;
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a file name or click the Get File List button");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a FTP address");
    }

    //Save Button
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (downloadedData != null && downloadedData.Length != 0)
        {
            if (saveFile1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.Text = "Saving Data...";
                Application.DoEvents();

                //Write the bytes to a file
                FileStream newFile = new FileStream(saveFile1.FileName, FileMode.Create);
                newFile.Write(downloadedData, 0, downloadedData.Length);
                newFile.Close();

                this.Text = "Download Data";
                MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please download first!");
    }

    //GetFile button
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileSize_down(txtFTPAddress.Text, txtFileName.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
    }



    }
    }
```

However, there is still a requirement that I did not know how to completed.
That is, when the downloading completes, the file location will automatically open with Window Explorer.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Use Process.Start("<folder path here>");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open Windows Explorer to a certain directory from within a WPF app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746079/how-can-i-open-windows-explorer-to-a-certain-directory-from-within-a-wpf-app)

Comment: I don't know but is Process.Start used to open file from a certain location? My program is after downloading you will choose to save the file to any location, and then after saving the file location automatically open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `btnSave_Click` event, try something like this after your line
`MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");`

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFile1.FileName);

System.Diagnostic.Process.Start("explorer", dir);
```