# How to manage different Programs At the same time in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**Detailed information about the software and project**

Hello,
I would like an exe program:

1°) Starting when windows starts ;

2°) First launching of the program: It opens a Windows Browser where I can show to the program the path of "nwserver.exe", then I can show to the program the path of "nwnxlite-loader.exe"

2°) That watchs if "nwserver.exe" is currently running (current path: E:\Steam\steamapps\common\Neverwinter Nights\bin\win32) ;

3°) If "nwserver.exe" crashes, it will, your choice:
A) First possibility: launch "nwnxlite-loader.exe" (current path: "E:\Steam\steamapps\common\Neverwinter Nights\bin\win32\nwnxlite-loader.exe") but with some specifics "-" commands included (ex: "E:\Steam\steamapps\common\Neverwinter Nights\bin\win32\nwnxlite-loader.exe" -module "Les_Naufragés_V1" -nwsyncurl "http://xxxx.com/nwsync"). We can imagine a menu button opening a text window where I can write down those "-" commands, but it will have to save those commands and load them "by default" after that, until I change them again with the same button.
B) Second possibilty: Just launch a shortcut on the desktop (path: C:\Users\JB-HOME\Desktop) that already has those "-" configuration commands inside the target field.

And that's it. I just need a crash checker for "nwserver.exe" that will launch "nwnxlite-loader.exe"

Comment: Have you tried writing it? Stack overflow is not a code writing service unfortunately.

Comment: Cool.. so you've got your list of requirements... what is the issue?  Where is the code?

Comment: Sorry, sir actually I don't have the way that how to start this out please help me?

Comment: [Run at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674628/how-do-i-set-a-program-to-launch-at-startup), [Run explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746079/how-can-i-open-windows-explorer-to-a-certain-directory-from-within-a-wpf-app), [Find a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187915/detecting-a-process-is-already-running-in-windows-using-c-sharp-net), [Launch an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-an-application-exe-from-c), [Execute a shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141821/run-application-via-shortcut-using-process-start-c-sharp)

Comment: The answers to all your questions are already on this site, please search around. I provided some links above. Give it a try, and come back if you get stuck on something specific!

Comment: okay Thank you  Rufus L